# Is it possible to create a \newcolumntype-like macro accepting more than one arguments where one of them is an optional argument?

Tags: tables, macros

Is it possible to create a `\newcolumntype`-like macro accepting more than one argument and one of them is an optional argument?

---

I want to create a column type `A` that can accept more than 1 argument such that I can create a tabular as follows:

```
\begin{tabular}{|A[2cm]{1cm}{5cm}|c|l|r|}
...
\end{tabular}
```

**Note:** the column type `A` accepts 3 arguments in this example.

Comment: Perhaps a bit more detail on what is wanted might be useful! I'm not sure if it is the macro `\newcolumntype` itself or the resulting letter that you want to alter.

Comment: @Joseph, please see my new edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Herbert has explained how to do mandatory arguments. Optional arguments is doable but requires some low-level hackery, auxiliary functions and is not for the faint-hearted. You can see two versions of the same approach in [numprint](http://ctan.org/pkg/numprint) and [siunitx](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) (the later is an adaptation of the former).

```
\makeatletter
\newtoks\mytoks
\mytoks\expandafter{\the\NC@list}
\newcolumntype{A}{}
\NC@list\expandafter{\the\mytoks \NC@do A}
\renewcommand*{\NC@rewrite@A}[3][]{%
  \@temptokena\expandafter{%
    \the\@temptokena 
      % INSERT DEFINITION HERE!
  }%
  \NC@find
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using `\csname NC@rewrite@A\endcsname` (and the `\expandafter`s) rather than `\NC@rewrite@A`?

Comment: @cgnieder Not here, but there is where I've copied it from! I'll edit.

Answer (score 8):

not with an optional argument, only with mandatory ones:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} 

\newcolumntype{A}[3]{@{\vrule\kern#1\vrule}p{#2}@{\vrule\kern#3\vrule}}
\begin{document} 

\begin{tabular}{|A{2cm}{1cm}{5cm}|c|l|r|}
foo & bar & baz & foobar
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: first of all thanks. However, if I define an optional argument as follow `\newcolumntype{A}[3][1cm]` and  `\begin{tabular}{|A[2cm]{1cm}{5cm}|c|l|r|}`, I got compilation errors.

Comment: I wrote "_not_" with an optional argument!

Answer (score 1):

starting off with [Joseph Wright's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8005) I have developed a hack which allows to define new column types with an optional parameter with the `\newcolumntype` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% ---------- hack to allow optional parameters with \newcolumntype ----------
\makeatletter
% newcommand with default value for optional parameter but without test whether command exists
% because array package has a different policy: warning instead of error if column type is already defined
\def\@xargdef@withoutcheck#1[#2][#3]#4{%
    % copied from \show\@xargdef without \@ifdefinable
    % also see The LaTeX 2e Sources (2014/05/01 p24f)
    \expandafter \def \expandafter #1\expandafter {%
        \expandafter \@protected@testopt \expandafter #1\csname \string #1\endcsname {#3}%
    }%
    \expandafter \@yargdef \csname \string #1\endcsname \tw@ {#2}{#4}%
}

% save a backup of original command which I am going to override
\let\original@newcol@\newcol@

% redefine a command which is internally called by \newcolumntype.
% check whether column type is already existing has already been done
% and existence of first optional argument (number of parameters) has been confirmed,
% see array package documentation (November 3, 2014 p21f).
% check whether 2nd optional argument is given:
\def\newcol@#1[#2]{%
    \@ifnextchar[%
        {\my@newcol@#1[#2]}%
        {\original@newcol@#1[#2]}%
}

% custom command which handles 2nd optional argument (default value of optional parameter)
\def\my@newcol@#1[#2][#3]#4{\expandafter\@xargdef@withoutcheck\csname NC@rewrite@#1\endcsname[#2][#3]{\NC@find#4}}
\makeatother


% ---------- example usage ----------
\newcolumntype{m}[1][c]{>{$} #1 <{$}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1][c]{>{\displaystyle}m[#1]}

\newcolumntype{A}[3][0em]{>{\typeout{opt: #1}\rule[#1]{#2}{#3}} l <{\rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}


% ---------- test document ----------
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{M[l] M M[r]}
    \toprule
    a+b=c & a+b=c & a+b=c \\
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\bigskip

Please note that in this case it is necessary to add curley braces around the optional argument because otherwise the `m' of the unit would be interpreted as a column specifier:
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{A{1em}{.5pt} A[{.3em}]{1em}{.5pt}}
    \toprule
    1 & a\\ 
    2 & b\\
    3 & c\\
    hello & world \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s easy peasy with `tblr` environment of my new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray). You can use `\NewColumnType` command to create a new column type `A` with one optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\NewColumnType{A}[3][0em]{>{\rule[#1]{#2}{#3}} l <{\rule[#1]{#2}{#3}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{A{1em}{.5pt} A[.3em]{1em}{.5pt}}
  \toprule
    1 & a\\ 
    2 & b\\
    3 & c\\
    hello & world \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]